# How can I have column E copy its data into the right column based on the initials in column M?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So what I have so far is a spreadsheet that will auto time stamp column N when my technicians enter their initials into column M.

Now the 2nd thing I would like the spreadsheet to do is.

When I enter the hours (example: 1.8) into column E "HRS." And have the spreadsheet put the HRS. into the correct Technicians column. Based on the initials entered in column M "Tech Up".

Example: if E4=1.8 it would put 1.8 into G4 because M4=AB

 
Example: if E6=3.2 it would put 3.2 into J6 because M6=JW

Does anyone know what type formula this would require? Or where I might look to find one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data starts in row 4, and the individual technician columns start at column G, try in G4:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(E4:E*(M4:M={"AB","CD","GM","JW","RT"});E4:E;IFERROR(1/0)))`

and if the initials of the technicians are already in G2:L2 as headers:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(E4:E*(M4:M=G2:L2);E4:E;IFERROR(1/0)))`

Notes if using the first option:

1. Change the initials in the embedded array to match your columns
2. If your spreadsheet is set to a locale that uses commas as a decimal, change the commas in the embedded array to \

Comment: The code above is what i used. Thank you so much for your answer. I will have to try it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to how I think your sheet is structured (from your comment).